# How to fix "VirtualBox VM quit unexpectedly" when running my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM on MacOS Catalina 10.15 in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos

I am running VirtualBox 6.1 on Catalina 10.15.6 and when I start my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VM it says "VirtualBox VM quit unexpectedly". How can I fix this?

The Apple report is below

```
Path:                  /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBoxVM
Identifier:            org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBoxVM
Version:               6.1.14 (6.1.14)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        VBoxSVC [2581]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-09-12 11:06:06.400 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G73)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.6 (17P6065)
Anonymous UUID:        D239C6C6-47E5-4E96-B087-5A70B7918F9D


Time Awake Since Boot: 1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        34  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace TCC, Code 0x0

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Answer (score 35):

Go to Settings > Audio and uncheck "Enable Audio". There seems to be a bug that crashes Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in VirtualBox when it attempts to check audio input permissions with CoreAudio.

00:00:32.681184 CoreAudio: macOS 10.14+ detected, checking audio input permissions

(then the system crashes...)

Comment: That worked like a charm.

Comment: yep, that was the secret sause. Cheers @brstream !

Comment: thank you, this saved it!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This also solved the same error message that appeared when I tried to use virtual machine with the Debian 10.6.0 amd64 .iso.

Comment: Thank you! worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me, running Kali 2020.3 in Virtual Box on Mac OS 10.15.6 (Catalina)

Comment: Worked like a charm! using virtual box 6.1.14 running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Works! Do you know how to enable audio back?

Answer (score 10):

For me. I tried two solutions (pick one):

1. Starting virtualbox with sudoer works for me.
2. Disable Audio also works
   settings->Audo--> uncheck Enable Audio.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `sudo` way. That’s also mentioned [in this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659732).

Answer (score 3):

All of the above is good info, but you have to dig down into the discussion a bit further if you're using bash.

I use bash, and the workaround from the discussion that worked for me was to start the gui with

```
    zsh -i -c virtualbox
```

Afterwards, I tried starting a vm via the commandline, e.g.

```
    vboxmanage startvm foobar
```

and that worked, too.

Comment: This one is the **only** one that worked for me. Doing so, virtualbox asked for microphone permissions, and did NOT crash!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

> **VM Crashing with Termination Reason: Namespace TCC, Code 0x0
> (OSX/Mojava/Catalina)**
>
> Relevant bug thread:
> https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97141
>
> The Quick Fix:
>
> 1. Open a Terminal window.
> 2. Type 'virtualbox'.
> 3. Hit enter.
> 4. You should see Virtualbox open as usual (don't close the Terminal window, although you can minimize it).
> 5. Now that VirtualBox is running inside the Terminal process, it has permission to ask for permission to use your camera/microphone.
> 6. You can now launch your VM and should see a prompt asking you to allow it in the preferences.
> 7. Just keep your terminal open for the remainder of your VirtualBox session.
>
> A more effective solution should be forthcoming soon.

[source](https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/CS/Common_VirtualBox_Issues#VM_Crashing_with_Termination_Reason:_Namespace_TCC.2C_Code_0x0_.28OSX.2FMojava.2FCatalina.29)